# Disabled attribute not showing up on Html.Checkbox

Tags: html, razor, model-view-controller, checkbox

I am trying to display but disable checkboxes in MVC (I am aware that disabled checkboxes will still postback with a value of false).  However, I cannot get the checkboxes to be disabled.

Even adding the disabled attribute directly, the checkboxes remain enabled.

```
tableStyle: "table table-striped table-hover",
                fillEmptyRows: false,
                columns: grid.Columns
                    (
                    grid.Column("EnterpriseRxPlanID", canSort: false, format: (item) => Html.CheckBox("EnterpriseRxPlanID", isChecked: (bool)item.IsSelected, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control wp-check-erxpid", disabled = "" }), header: "Select"),
```

...

I've tried `disabled = "true"`, `@disabled = ""`, `@disabled = true`, etc, and the attribute is imply not rendered in the page.  If I add a new class, it shows up, so I know the page is being refreshed properly.

Any input is welcome, seems like such a small issue but I am befuddled.

Comment: Can you try like @disabled=disabled

Comment: The existence of `disabled` attribute (irrespective of the value) will make it disabled. Check your view source/elements in chrome dev tools and see the element has this attribute.

Comment: @Shyju that's the issue - no matter what I put in the httmlAttributes, it isn't showing up in the rendered HTML.

Comment: @Shyju so I now noticed though, if I add the disabled attribute, it renders a hidden input, as MVC is supposed to.  But the disabled attribute is being stripped from the checkbox.